# Using "à" in French with infinitives

Tags: prépositions, infinitif

I am aware that the infinitive of a verb in french is just the word not conjugated. But I noticed a lot of times that *à* is used in French when with infinitives. For example, when I was in Québec, my host family had a deep fryer. On the box, it said "ready to fry" and the French translation said "Prêt à frire". I know that "prêt" means ready, but mostly I don't understand why the "à" was necessary. "Frire" means "to fry" because it is in infinitive. Isn't the "to" in "to fry" already present within "frire"? I have the *à* with infinitives many times before, and I'm wondering when it is appropriate to use *à* with an infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

*À* is a preposition, it is used to introduce the prepositional phrase that serve to complement the sentence. And the rule says that after a preposition the verb must be in the infinitive, whether *à* or another preposition.

The choice of the preposition depends on what precedes the preposition and not on what comes after.

> Prêt à frire.

If you use a verb after *(être) prêt* then this verb is preceded by *à*, this *à* is not part of the infinitive as such, it is part of the verb phrase.

We have a different preposition after different expressions. For example:

> (J'ai) envie de partir.
>   (Je suis) heureux de rester.

Here it's *(avoir) envie de*, *être heureux de* that is followed by the infinitive, we don't have *à* but *de*.

Here is a related but not similar question: [When would one use “à” before a verb?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/368/when-would-one-use-%C3%A0-before-a-verb)

Comment: While « j’ai envie à partir » is totally incorrect, « je suis heureux à rester » may be used. Especially if there is a complement : « Je suis heureux à rester assis ». I cannot tell the difference and I'd say there is no difference.